# How to pass param object in form_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to pass object using form_tag.
Ease with form_for, i only use 
`<%= form_for @user, url: signup_path do |f| %>`. Every element htmt have name is `name=user[email] or name=user[password] or name=user[select]`. So in form_tag, i only do that with input type text, but can do that with Select, Radio, Password or something like that. So, How do i can pass 1 object with param like form_for to controller that use form_tag.

Comment: what have you tried so-far? post the code which you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just set name as the first parameter. Like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'user[email]' %>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It's that i need. :))